# How can I have a custom message for a duplicate key entered in a form?

Tags: ms-access

How can I have a custom message for a duplicate key?

In Design View of my table I turned "Indexed" on and I've chosen for YES(No Duplicates) but if I try to add a existing row again (in my Form) I get a default Access error message. I would like to make my own error message with a pop-up message box. But I have no idea how to make it. I tried to make a macro but I don't know how can you define that if rows are duplicated then you get a error message

Comment: I am afraid you will have to improve that question. What is an existing row? What code did you try? What went wrong?

Comment: In Design View of my table I turned "Indexed" on and I've chosen for YES(No Duplicates) but if i try to add a existing row again(in my Form) i get a default Access error message. I would like to make my own error message with a pop-up message box. But i have no idea how to make it. I tried to make a macro but i don't know how can you define that if rows are duplicated then you get a error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a form error event:

```
Private Sub Form_Error (DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
  Const REQUIREDFIELD_VIOLATION = 3314
  Const INPUTMASK_VIOLATION = 2279
  Const DUPLICATEKEY_VIOLATION = 3022
  If DataErr = DUPLICATEKEY_VIOLATION Then
     MsgBox "There was a key violation!"
     Response = acDataErrContinue
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I get argument not optional error!! My way of calling is `Private Sub TIN12Digit_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
Form_Error
End Sub`